# yajra datatable - laravel 5.7 my datatable is not working

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

WHAT M GETTING IN MY VIEW.

[see Datatable is not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sc6E.png)

THIS IS WHAT I DID.

providers = Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,

aliases = 'Datatables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,

my controller

```
use App\User;

use Datatables;

public function index(){
    $users = User::select('first_name','last_name');
    return Datatables::of($users)->make(true);
}


public function users(){
    return view('user.users');
}
```

my routes

```
Route::get('/users',  ['as' => 'user.users', 'uses' => 'UserController@users']);

Route::get('/index',  ['as' => 'user.index', 'uses' => 'UserController@index']);
```

my view in users.blade.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table1').DataTable({ 
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ url('index') }}",
        columns:[
            { data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name' },
            { data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name' }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Please clearly specify the error that you are getting.

Comment: Its `DataTables` instead of `Datatables` maybe the issue is a typo. https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/engine-eloquent

Comment: @linktoahref I think it depends on your aliases = 'Datatables' so it cant be a typo...this is what i think.

Comment: @linuxartisan i'm not getting any data table.

Comment: @Manoj what is the response(code and payload) you are getting from the ajax call to get the data tables

Comment: @linktoahref actually, the thing is I don't see any request made to index in console tool in the network section.

Comment: @Manoj in ajax function have you define "type" i mean "GET" or "POST"?

Comment: @sandy I haven't defined any post type in my ajax request to yajra datatables....i mean do i have to? I don't know because they haven't mentioned any post type in their examples.

Comment: ajax: {
                url: '/admin/lead-loan-statuses-ajax',
                type: 'POST',
                dataSrc: function (json) {
                    //can format data from here
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) { } } try like this

Comment: @sandy still no luck....as usual page loads with empty html table but no response form yajra datatables.

Comment: change your controller code                                                                          
 return DataTables::collection(yourModelName::get())->make(true); and also add alert in your js file so that you can identify what happed wether controll goes to ur js file or not

Comment: @sandy i don't think this is the issue because when i open this https.www.mydomain.com/index in my browser it gives me the desired data. but still, let me try that.

Comment: ok then console the response in js file wether you get data in response? i mean in js file?

Comment: have you check id attribute of your table is it "table1" ?

Comment: yes i have gone through it all but the weird thing is i don't see any request made to /index from my console.

Comment: https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter may be this will help you

Comment: It seems a bit different...let me try this 
and could you explain me this?

ajax: '{!! route('datatables.data') !!}',

Comment: route('datatables.data') it is used to access named route. if you give any name in your route Ex. Route::get('/index','HomeController@index')->name('home'); then you can access it like route('home');

Comment: Thanks for wanting to provide a self-answer. Please do that in the answer space below, rather than mixing it in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simply put **defer** in my **dataTables.min.js** script.

see here :

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue or not but a potential problem. You have not gotten the data from the query builder.

Try something like this.

```
public function index(){ 
    $users  = User::select('first_name','last_name')->get(); 
    return Datatables::of($users)->make(true); 
}
```

Adding the `->get()` fetches the data.

Comment: thank you for this but m still stuck with my issue. :(